# Unable to capture Sec-WebSocket-Key

Tags: c#, websocket

Moving on with my attempt to create a web socket server.  I have success at capturing the headers from the client (shown in the image), but my code fails to capture the Sec-WebSocket-Key that is needed.  What I noticed is that when the server runs it goes through an accept process twice:  first for the website, and second for the websocket client inside the website).  I'm trying not to use the HttpListener class because it is built on top of HTTP.sys.

I'm looking for help on how to capture the Sec-WebSocket-Key.

My code gives the following output.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TkJx.png)

The server code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\file", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(""), );
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("server running:  " + server.LocalEndpoint.ToString());
            int accept_count = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = server.AcceptSocket();
                int count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("‐--------------------");
                string ip = ((IPEndPoint)(socket.RemoteEndPoint)).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(ip + "   " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("accept:  " + accept_count);

                string header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
                string content_data = "<!doctype html><html><body>hello world, the date is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                        "<script type = \"text/javascript\">" +
                            "var websocket = new WebSocket(\"wss://156.96.119.19:443\");" +
                        "</script >" +
                    "</body></html>";
                string data = header + content_data;
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToCharArray(), 0, (int)data.Length);

                SslStream stream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(socket, true));
                stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, true);

                if (accept_count == 0)
                {
                    accept_count++;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int i = stream.ReadByte();
                            if (i == -1) break;
                            char c = (char)i;
                            if (c == '\n')
                            {
                                if (count == 1)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Write(c);
                                }
                                count = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Write(c);
                                count++;
                            }

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("end of stream reached");


                }
                else if (accept_count == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("reading");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int i = stream.ReadByte();
                            Console.Write(i + "   ");
                            if (i == -1) break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                            Console.ReadLine();

                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("reading complete");


                }



                stream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
                stream.Close();





            }
```

I'm looking at this article:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

My code uses a secure socket layer.

Comment: I web client/listener and web socket are different. A client creates a new connection for each request/response.   A socket the connection stays open until closed.  You are creating a two port application where the server on one port is a client/listener and second port is a socket.  It looks like you are opening the client/socket is chunk mode http 1.1 (not stream mode 1.0).  A socket is http 2.0.  The client is working properly, the socket is failing.

Comment: I would read the article carefully and step through the HANDSHAKING code and make sure each step is valid.  The GUID 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11 may not be in the computer registry.  You can check with RegEdit (registry editor).  This is not the same as Regex which is also used in the code.